# Big difference in pdf size using Puppeteer and print as pdf from Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, puppeteer

I have this problem with creating PDF's, my setup is like this, i have express server that is rendering handlebars template with provided data. Puppeteer is going to that local url and is generating pdf file. That generated file is around 27MB which is insanely big. What confuses me is that if I go to that same url and generate pdf with print function of browser, pdf is around 600KB. I can provide any information to debug this, thanks for help.

```
const url = `http://localhost:4000/jigs?data=${JSON.stringify({
    batchName: 'asdasd342',
    date: 'Wed 2021',
    page: 1,
    totalPages: 1,
    order: {
      numberOfBoards: 1,
      date: 'Wed 2021',
      id: '123123123asdwqd',
    },
    customer: {
      name: 'name',
      address: 'street 22',
      city: 'city',
      zipCode: 5000,
      country: 'usa',
    },
    images: [
      {
        url: 'https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Iunctus_SPOT5_5m_8bit_RGB_DRA_torngat_mountains_national_park_8bits_1.jpg',
      },
    ],
  })}`;
```

```
app2.get('/jigs', (req, res) => {
  const { data } = req.query;
  res.render('slips', { ...JSON.parse(data), layout: false });
});
```

```
const pdf = await page.pdf({
    path: 'output.pdf',
    printBackground: true,
    width: `8.25in`,
    height: `8.25in`,
  });
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/styles.css' />
    <style>
      html, body { width: 11.68in; height: 8.25in; } .image-grid {
      grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr); grid-template-columns: repeat(10,
      1fr); }
    </style>
    <title>Jigs template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>
        <img alt='logo' src='assets/images/logo.svg' />
        <div class='info-order'>
          <p>Batch name: {{batchName}}</p>
          <p>Page {{page}} of {{totalPages}}</p>
          <p>Date: {{date}}</p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class='image-grid'>
        {{#each images}}
          <div>
            <img alt='image' src='{{this.url}}' />
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why but it seems to me that css is increasing pdf size by a lot.

Comment: When you say you tried using the print function of the browser, what are the dimensions you chose? Probably A4? Because A4 is 210×297 mm, which is way smaller than 8.25×8.25 in.

Comment: Yes I was using A4.

Comment: Which is exactly the reason the browser version of the PDF is smaller

Comment: A4 is 8.27 x 11.69 in, I don't see how is that smaller than 8.25 × 8.25 in.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpretation of internet info

Comment: When you say CSS increases size a lot, which CSS? the code inside `<style>`?

Comment: I am not sure is it just css inside <style> or from css file, but my pdf went from 50KB to 400KB just by adding css to it.

Comment: 350 KB is not that much, it's the 27 MB that we seek to improve, can you show us the full puppeteer code? Also, when debugging puppeteer code, try launching it without headless mode and have a `debugger` operation before `page.pdf` statement and then print.

Comment: were you able to figure it out? Experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: @NikitaFedorov not really but on PDF service I created after successful PDF document creation I push it thru ghostscript to get very small document, if you need help with this ping me and I will provide you with help.